# 70s-80s SF book, a series of short stories each set X years ahead. In first one aliens placed domes over cities before wiping out everyone else

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, alien-invasion, anthology-book

I read this years ago, most likely this would be a young adult book, maybe from the 1970s or 1980s.  I swear the title was "The Turning Point: Tales of a Future Past" but I've never been able to find it under that name so I may be remembering something wrong.

In the first story aliens put domes on cities and eventually the domes expand, destroying anything and anyone not in a dome.  I think this was called "the sweep".  Each story was set farther into the future, showing some of the repercussions of the earlier story.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[*The Turning Place: Stories of a Future Past*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?39731), a 1976 collection by [Jean E. Karl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_E._Karl) in her [*Clordian Sweep*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?28300) series.

[image: The Turning Place 1976 cover]
[image: The Turning Place 2016 cover]

Review by [Charles N. Brown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_N._Brown) in [*Isaac Asimov's Science Fiction Magazine*, Spring 1977](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?59294), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Asimovs_v01n01_1977-Spring#page/n149/mode/1up):

> The biggest joy in reviewing books is to come across something very good but obscure. My 'discovery' this year is Jean Karl's *The Turning Place*, subtitled *Stories of a Future Past*. Although packaged as a juvenile collection of science fiction stories, it's actually a novel, since each story builds upon the one before it. In the first story, an alien race destroys civilization and nearly wipes out humanity. Each successive story, set several generations later, shows how people have changed, adapted, and set up a new social order which is better than the old one. Some stories are straight juveniles, others are not — especially the later, complex ones. The quality of the writing, as with most juveniles, is quite good.

From a comment by [DavidW](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/101407/davidw):

> Google Books has a [preview of the first story](https://books.google.ca/books?id=vGZODAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false): a dome appears in the desert, the protagonist and a few others are trapped inside, and then the dome expands out over the countryside, leaving nothing behind for them to find.

Comment: Oh god, thanks for this!  I loved this book and thought I'd never find it again!!

Comment: You're welcome!